# How do you match 12 hour time hh:mm in a regex?

Tags: php, regex, datetime, time

How could you match 12 hour time in a regex-- in other words match 12:30 but not 14:74?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried this: (1?[0-9]):([0-9]{2}) but that matches 14:74!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work:

```
([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Comment: Note that this one matches "3:00" in "13:00".

Comment: The above still fails for "13:00" (by matching "3:00"), and doesn't match "00:00".

Comment: ([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9] -- just for kicks.

Comment: @tvanfosson My thoughts exactly ;)

Comment: @Cide: True, but Adrian did not define a delimitter.  We could, of course, prepend it with [^\d].

Comment: @Brian I'd vote for \b or a lookbehind for (?<!\d) to avoid capturing anything but the time. (Semantics aside, I totally agree.) And 00:00 isn't a 12-hour time; that's written 12:00.

Comment: This matches parts of times over 12:59 (e.g. on 13:23 it matches 3:23)

Answer (score 16):

This is an example of a problem where "hey I know, I'll use regular expressions!" is the wrong solution. You can use a regular expression to check that your input format is digit-digit-colon-digit-digit, then use programming logic to ensure that the values are within the range you expect. For example:

```
/(\d\d?):(\d\d)/

if ($1 >= 1 && $1 <= 12 && $2 < 60) {
    // result is valid 12-hour time
}
```

This is much easier to read and understand than some of the obfuscated regex examples you see in other answers here.

Comment: Or it is an example where you are filling out something that requires regular expressions...

Answer (score 8):

```
^(00|0[0-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9] ?((a|p)m|(A|P)M)$
```

`^` - Match the beginning of the string.

`(00|0[0-9]|1[012])` -  any two-digit number up to 12. Require two digits.

`:` - Match a colon

`[0-5][0-9]` - Match any two-digit number from 00 to 59.

`?` - Match a space zero or one times.

`((a|p)m|(A|P)M)` - Match am or pm, case insensitive.

`$` - Match the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Like this: `((?:1[0-2]|0\d)\:(?:[0-5]\d))` if you want leading 0 for the hour, `((?:1[0-2]|\d)\:(?:[0-5]\d))` if you don't and `((?:1[0-2]|0?\d)\:(?:[0-5]\d))` if you don't care.

Comment: That would mandate a leading 0 wouldn't it?  e.g. would match 05:02 but not 5:02?

Comment: fixed that: you want, you don't or you don't care :)

Answer (score 1):

why regex? you can do this will simple integer check

```
$str = "12:74";
list($h , $m ) = explode(":",$str);
if ( ($h <=12 && $h >=0  ) && ($m <=59 && $m >=0) ) {
    print "Time Ok.";
}else{
    print "Time not ok";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but if `$str` is equal to `"foozah"`, it will break your script (as there's no index 1). Also, if `$str` is equal to `"foo:zah"`, your script will say that it *is* a valid time, but I like to think that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:(?:1?(?:[0-2]))|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the above fail in at least one way, particularly regarding strings such as "13:00" (Keith's matches "3:00" in that case).

This one should handle that issue as well as the others brought up.

```
([01][0-2]|(?<!1)[0-9]):([0-5][0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(0?\d|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)
```

That will match everything from 0:00 up to 12:59. That's 13 hours, by the way. If you don't want to match 0:00 - 0:59, try this instead:

```
([1-9]|1[0-2]):([0-5]\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one:

```
/((?:1[0-2])|(?:0?[0-9])):([0-5][0-9]) ?([ap]m)/

/1 => hour
/2 => minute
/3 => am/pm
```

Answer (score 0):

The following matches padded and non-padded hours in a 24hr clock (i.e. 00:00 - 23:59) between 00:00 and 12:59.

```
(?:(?<!\d)[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9]
```

Matches:

- 00:00
- 00:58
- 01:34
- 1:34
- 8:35
- 12:23
- 12:59

Nonmatches:

- 13:00
- 13:23
- 14:45
- 23:59

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 12 hour pattern with AM and PM validation.

`TIME12HOURSAMPM_PATTERN = "^(?:(?<!\\d)[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?((a|p)m|(A|P)M)$";`