# How to validate time using && in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working with a time validation and I'm confused on how to `validate` this `start_time` and `end_time` using &&. I have this code so far:

```
     var re = /^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})([ap]m)?$/;
    //Start Time
    if($('.start_time').val() != '') {
              if(regs = $('.start_time').val().match(re)) {
                if(regs[3]) {
                  // 12-hour value between 1 and 12
                  if(regs[1] < 1 || regs[1] > 12) {
                    $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for hour(s)</div>');
                    $('.start_time').focus();
                    return false;
                  }
                } else {
                    if(regs[1] > 12){
                    $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for hour(s)</div>');
                    return false;
                    }
                }
                // minute value between 0 and 59
                if(regs[2] > 59) {
                  $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for minute(s)</div>');
                  $('.start_time').val().focus();
                  return false;
                }
              } else {
                $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Invalid time format</div>');
                $('.start_time').focus();
                return false;
              }
              $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Checked</div>');
              return true;
            }else{
                $('.start_time_error').html('<div>Please fill up</div>');
                return false;
            }
            //End time----------
              if($('.end_time').val() != '') {
              if(regs = $('.end_time').val().match(re)) {
                if(regs[3]) {
                  // 12-hour value between 1 and 12
                  if(regs[1] < 1 || regs[1] > 12) {
                    $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for hour(s)</div>');
                    $('.end_time').focus();
                    return false;
                  }
                } else {
                    if(regs[1] > 12){
                    $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for hour(s)</div>');
                    return false;   
                    }
                }
                // minute value between 0 and 59
                if(regs[2] > 59) {
                  $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Invalid value for minute(s)</div>');
                  $('.end_time').val().focus();
                  return false;
                }
              } else {
                $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Invalid time format</div>');
                $('.end_time').focus();
                return false;
              }
              $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Checked</div>');
              return true;
            }else{
                $('.end_time_error').html('<div>Please fill up</div>');
                return false;
            }
```

I tried something like:

```
  if(regs = $('.start_time').val().match(re) && regss == $('.end_time').val().match(re) )
```

But didn't work for me it sends and error `regss is not defined`. Any alternatives on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Why so many error messages? Why not just "you have entered an invalid time" and validate with one single regex? Then show a placeholder so user understands the format.

Comment: @elclanrs: How to validate with one single regex? Pardon i'm new to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're complicating things... Think about separation of concerns. In your logic you have 2 main blocks, the validation for the time string, and the DOM manipulation to extract those values and print the error. In your current code you're repeating the same logic twice for two fields, why not abstract that into a function?

Then I think is not worth printing multiple errors, if the time is invalid, then say something like "you entered an invalid time" and let the user know the right format, with a placeholder in the input, or in the generic error message.

If you follow this advice you can probably reduce your code by **a lot** and make cleaner and easier to understand. Here's an example, I adapted the regex from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190451/how-do-you-match-12-hour-time-hhmm-in-a-regex):

```
function isTime(str) {
  return /^([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9]\s*?(am|pm)$/i.test(str);
}
```

Now you can validate your inputs like so:

```
var start = $.trim($('.start_time').val())
  , end = $.trim($('.end_time').val());

if (!isTime(start) || !isTime(end)) {
  $('.generic_error').html('<div>Please enter a valid time (HH:MM AM/PM)</div>');
}
```

Not sure about your HMTL but this should give an overall idea on how to abstract your code to make it DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ayAbUyI/1/edit

Comment: Works fine here http://jsbin.com/ayAbUyI/1/edit. You just need to find a way to adapt your code and markup, this is not meant for straight copy/paste.