# Regular expression data time 12hrs format

Tags: regex

Hello I have problem with my regular expression. I need data and format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS but only 12 hours. What's wrong?

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})_(\s((([1-9])|(1[02]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))$
```

Comment: What do you mean by "but only 12 hours"?

Comment: There might be a syntax error `^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4})_(  <-- Unbalanced  '('
\s(  <-- Unbalanced  '('
(([1-9])|(1[02]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))$`

Comment: I mean 12 hrs format for example 11 pm not 23

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you match 12 hour time hh:mm in a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190451/how-do-you-match-12-hour-time-hhmm-in-a-regex)

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this

```
Year-Month    /^\d{4}-([0][1-9] | [1][0-2] )
Day of Month  -([0][1-9] | [1-2]\d | [3][0-1])
Hour          \s([0][1-9] | [1][0-2])
Minute        :([0-5]\d)
Second        : ([0-5]\d)$/
```

breakdown

`^` - Start of regex

`\d{4}`- Matches any four digits

`()` - Capture everything enclosed

`|` - a or b

`[0][1-9]` - Will match a 0 followed by any positive digit

`[1][0-2]` - Or a 1 followed by a 0,1 or 2

`[0-2]\d` - For months, any number between 0 and 2 can be followed by any digit

`[3][0-1]` - If the first digit of the date of the month is a 3, it can only be followed by a 0 or a 1.

`$` - End of regex

You can test it out online.

Comment: I think your minutes are only going from 0-12 and not 0-60, and seconds have a similar problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got confused with all of the numbers we were dealing with. I just reformatted it so it will be easier to follow

Comment: For completeness, hour should be changed to from [0]\d to [0][1-9], 00 is not a valid time for a 12 hour clock.

Comment: do not work / error: ([0][1-9] <-- here Unmatched opening parenthesis

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't notice that

Comment: Hmm but this still don't work. I try for example 1993-02-02 11:11:11 and nothing